# BIND forwards without using forwarders

Tags: dns, bind, x11-forwarding

I've a BIND DNS configured, all works ok. The configuration has no forwarders, but if I ping Google, I get an anwser. This behaviour is not normal, beacause there is no way to access "external" network. In `etc/resolv.conf` I have only my server IP (no secondary DNS).

There is no special configuration done, I have only created a zone, a pair of A and CNAME registers and that's all.

Is there a special setting in new Bind versions (I'm using 9.10) which enables forwarding automatically or something? I'm really lost with this issue...

Thank you all.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no way to access 'external' network"?

Comment: Hi:

I mean that I have configured a local DNS, without forwarding. There is no secondary DNS pointing to 8.8.8.8 for example, or an active forward zone. Because of this, DNS resolution should be only locally, not externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no forwarder, your server queries the DNS root servers directly.

What you want to do is to disable recursive queries so that your server will refuse to answer queries about domains other than the ones it is in charge of. This is the default behaviour in recent versions of BIND, but usually it is overridden with something like

```
allow-recursion { myservers; myclients; };
```

to allow trusted clients to perform recursive queries. Just modify it accordingly.